# Weighted sum of elements in matrix - Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum, weighted

I have two `50 x 6` matrices, say `A` and `B`. I want to assign weights to each element of columns in matrix - more weight to elements occurring earlier in a column and less weight to elements occurring later in the same column...likewise for all 6  columns. Something like this:

```
cumsum(weight(row)*(A(row,col)-B(row,col)); % cumsum is for cumulative sum of matrix
```

How can we do it efficiently without using loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your weight vector `w` as a `50x1` vector, then you can rewrite your code as

```
cumsum(repmat(w,1,6).*(A-B))
```

BTW, I don't know why you have the `cumsum` operating on a scalar in a loop... it has no effect. I'm assuming that you meant that's what you *wanted* to do with the entire matrix. Calling `cumsum` on a matrix will operate along each column by default. If you need to operate along the rows, you should call it with the optional dimension argument as `cumsum(x,2)`, where `x` is whatever matrix you have.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, instead of `cumsum(repmat(w,1,6).*(A-B))`, `sum(sum(repmat(w,1,6).*(A-B)))` is the one I was looking for.

Comment: @S_H: In that case, this will be a marginally better option: `W=repmat(w,1,6);sum(W(:).*(A(:)-B(:)))` Note that in this case there is only one call to the function `sum` instead of two. While you might not notice any difference for this example, it's good to remember, especially when you're working with bigger matrices or in a loop, where the additional overhead becomes significant.